# Whats is exactly the difference between invocationCount and IRetryAnalyzer approach in TestNG?

Tags: testng

I was trying my hands on TestNG, then i faced two attributes which can be used to retry the failed testcase.One is to use invocationCount and other to implement IRetryAnalyzer interface, what exactly is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically `IRetryAnalyzer` is an interface with a `retry` method declaration. This method is used to analyze a test result in order to make a decision whether the test method has to be rerun.

So `IRetryAnalyzer` is about making the decision based on a test result.
The `invocationCount` does not evaluate test result. It is a simple counter.

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz, I have tried them today and observed a major difference that doesn't matter the result is fail or pass invocationCount will reexecute it, on the other hand retryAnalyzer takes control only if result is failed, if I am right?

Comment: No. It takes control regardless of the result, but it can read the result. The `invocationCount` does not have access to the test result.